# Computing limit of wonky function

Tags: limits, functions

Let $f(x) = \exp\left(-2^{1/3}\right) - \exp\left(-2^\frac{x}{3x-1}\right)$. I want to compute
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} e^x f(x)
$$

which according to the grapher is $+\infty$. It's been a while since I've computed limits, and the limit I'm getting is $-\infty$ instead:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} e^x f(x) 
&= \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\exp\left(-2^{1/3}\right)e^x - \exp\left(x-2^\frac{x}{3x-1}\right) \\
&= \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \exp\left(-2^{1/3}\right)e^x - \exp\left(x\,(1-\frac{1}{x}\,2^\frac{x}{3x-1})\right) \\
&= \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \exp\left(-2^{1/3}\right)e^x - \exp(x(1-0)) \\
&= \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} e^x \left(e^{-2^{1/3}}-1\right) \\
= -\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: @AndrewLi Thank you Andrew. I think I did so, since the beginning.

Comment: How did you get $\exp(x(1-0))$ from the previous line? I mean, $2^{\frac x{3x-1}}$ goes to $2^{\frac 13}$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: You can write the limit in the form $f(x)/e^{-x}$ the use l'Hopital's rule. This will rid you of the constant term. From there I suggest you use an inequality to show that the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you. 0 is because $\frac{1}{x}\,2^\frac{x}{3x-1}$ goes to 0 as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime worked like a charm! Thanks!